# Stream matching from String array

Tags: java, java-stream

i'm testing some Java 8 stream operations right now and i'm confused about following behaviour.

Having this simple test:

```
public static void main(final String[] args) {

    final String[] arr = { "-e", "-f", "-t" };
    System.out.println(Arrays.stream(arr).anyMatch(x -> x == "-e"));

}
```

That works fine as results in an expected "true".
But, if i try match the "args" list instead the arr-array with content "-e" it won't work as expected and results in "false".

Strange, hmm?

Can anybody tell me whats wrong?

Comment: `x == "-e"` isn't what you want. Read the linked question.

Comment: Thanks, thats true, how stupid can one be ...